# How to Set the default value after sorting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-select

I am sorting my dropdown by this code.

```
var bindSortselect= function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).children("option").sort(function (a, b) {
            console.log(a.text);
            console.log(b.text);
            return a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase() ? 0 : a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1
        }));    
    });
};
```

But I want specific Item to be selected by default(by user)after sorting.for example: if I apply above code generally for all "select" tag It sort it out and then set the default value like if I select "DZD" from dropdown so after sorting "DZD" remain selected.

```
<select id="id_currency" name="currency">
    <option value="AFN"></option>
    <option value="DZD"></option>
    <option value="ARS"></option>
    <option value="AMD"></option>
    <option value="AWG"></option>
    <option value="AUD"></option>
    ...
    <option value="BND"></option>
</select>
```

Kindly reply.Thanks in Advance

Comment: keep the value by  var theSelectedVal = $("select").val(), then after the sort, use $("select").val(theSelectedVal)

Comment: Pass the value to be selected in the function bindSortselect and select the value after sorting is done.

Comment: Anum Aquil, i edited your question for indentation and redability, something went wrong and i deleted the "THB" option. If it was important, i invite you to regress your question to previous edition, i cannot do it. Sorry.

Comment: I am not getting actually can you please re-write the code and send it over here.As I am new in JavaScript.

Comment: @HarryBomrah there is no need to pass value, you can make use of selectors.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan but how you ll know which value to set.  If you read he wants to make a particular value selected, not the which were already selected. so he has to pass the values in some way so that the function knows which value to be selected.

Comment: @HarryBomrah that is where [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are used.

Answer (score 1):

Before sorting store the `value` of **`select`** tag in a variable,

```
var ch = $("select").val(); //fetch the value of select
```

Once sorted, set this back as value

```
$("select").val(ch);  //set the value to select
```

Finally,

```
var bindSortselect= function() {
    var ch = $("select").val(); //fetch the value of select
    $("select").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).children("option").sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase() ? 0 : a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1
        }));    
    });
    $("select").val(ch);  //set the value to select
};
```

Comment: Im not getting actually can you please re-write the code and send it over here.As Im new in Javascript.

Comment: this is not returnng the selected value.It is just returning the very 1st value slected.Please look into this again.

Comment: I got it Praveen :) its working now Thanks ALottt :)

Comment: @AnumAquil oh, glad to hear you fixed it :) I was trying to create a fiddle